# Set the defaultMessage to look at "en-US" if the current locale is missing entry

Tags: react-intl

Rather than specify a defaultMessage for every FormattedMessage, it would be nice to set the defaultMessage to always be that of a particular language. We know we are always going to have English translations for everything. Specifically I'd like to set the defaultMessage to look at "en-US" if the current locale is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Created a util for this:

```
export function getDefaultText(id: IntlMessages.FM): string {
    return IntlMessages.default["en-US"].hasOwnProperty(id) ? IntlMessages.default["en-US"][id] : ""
}

export function formatMessageId(intl: ReactIntl.InjectedIntl, id: IntlMessages.FM) {
    return intl.formatMessage({
        id: id,
        defaultMessage: getDefaultText(id)
    })
}
```